# How to force https on routes play framework

Tags: scala, http, ssl, https, playframework-2.5

Using Play Framework 2.5.6
I have secured my application with SSL.
Now, page is loaded with https I figured out this error.

Mixed Content: The page at ‘’ was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ‘’. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

because on page i use rest endpoints (http) to fetch data.
I have multiple rest endpoints to fetch the data.

Is there any support that I can configure at one place like application.config,
and all rest endpoints in routes will use https instead of http??